# Null value in query where a result is expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have `[strStockNumber] + [strCustomerNumber] + [intAccountNumber] as "REFNUMBER"` in a select where the column `strStockNumber = 148218X` and the other two columns are null. The returned `REFNUMBER` is null, where I'm expecting `148218X`Does + not concatenate nulls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` values concatenate to a `null` value.

If you want to still concatenate the values you will need to wrap them in a `isnull(<Column>,'')` like so:

```
isnull(strStockNumber,'')
  + isnull(strCustomerNumber,'')
  + isnull(intAccountNumber,'') as "REFNUMBER"
```

Answer (score 3):

> Does + not concatenate nulls?

No..Null+ any thing equals nulls..You will have to use `ISNULL` to get desired results

Answer (score 2):

Use CONCAT to join strings with possible NULL values:

```
CONCAT ([strStockNumber], [strCustomerNumber], [intAccountNumber]) AS [REFNUMBER]
```